# Why custom sound pauses in background state with iOS and Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used AVAudioPlayer. I want to play custom sound when app is in background state. Now, when entering in background state sound stops and when back to foreground it resumes. Why does this happen?

Comment: Have you looked into using `AVAudioSession` and setting an audio category?

Comment: You need to improve your question. Like this it is unclear how we could help you. You could improve your question by showing some code and by showing what you have tried so far and what has not worked out the way you think it should have.

Answer (score 1):

Project file -> Capabilities -> Background modes -> Put checkmark on "Audio, Airplay.."
[image: Put checkmark on first one]